# 'Suggested edit queue is full' displayed on every question I try to edit

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I've tried editing more than 20 questions as a test and they all showed that `Suggested edit queue is full` message. Then I tried again literally 4 seconds after a question was uploaded (when I clicked the question it showed *just now*) and again got the same message, as you can see from the picture below:

[image]

Are there some kind of bans that prevents from editing? But even that wouldn't make sense, since I haven't done so many edits and like 98% of them were accepted. Are those bots?

Comment: The queue is shared between all questions. If it is full you can't propose an edit for any question.

Comment: What site? Stack Overflow?

Comment: I think 98% says more about the reviewers than you. In [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73405235/how-to-use-webshare-api-for-multiple-post-in-the-blogger-postsnippet), you failed to capitalise "i", failed to capitalise a sentence, failed to add the missing punctuation, and failed to add a missing question mark. These are all changes that require very little skill. Some [articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) were also missing. *Please*, *please* fix ***all*** problems with a post, not just formatting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this (accepted) [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534146/eclipse-error-icon-not-showing/73358952#73358952) a word that was very obviously missing wasn't added and missing punctuation wasn't added. Slightly more complicated was [a spelling mistake](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maybe#Adverb). You could also have enabled [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-wok/184109#184109) (<backtick> <backtick> <backtick> lang-xml) while you were at it (not so important, though).

Comment: In [this formatting change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73401578/could-not-create-task-generatelockfiles), syntax highlighting should be turned ***off*** (e.g., with code fence [<backtick> <backtick> <backtick> lang-none](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-wok/184109#184109)). The syntax highlighting becomes very weird if it isn't done. This is mostly a fault of the current syntax highlighter and how it is implemented by Stack Overflow the company, but we have to adapt to it. Or in other words, any error message formatted as -

Comment: cont' - code should, as a general rule, have syntax highlighting turned off. Whether error messages should be formatted as code or quoted is another discussion.

Comment: For looking up the spelling of tech words, you are welcome to use [my service](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Dot%20Net).

Comment: Meta information, like *"[I really need some help, Big Thanks!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73405317/undefined-is-not-an-object-filter-data-from-apis)"* and *"[I hope this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328180/inject-specific-values-from-custom-configuration-tree/73348159#73348159)"* should also [be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) while you are at it—you are already doing it to some extent. If the posters really insist on it, they can add it in comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips :)
 I'm constantly trying to improve, but sometimes I tend to focus too much on the code formatting and forget some of the rest. I also didn't know about the **\`\`\`lang-none** thing, so I guess I learned something new